# Executing Vlookup through shortcut keys excel VBA

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to execute Vlookup through keyboard shortcut. I initially tried to use vlookup through the quick access toolbar, but i dont see any specific command button for it.
My second method is to have a macro in personal macro workbook to display the function argument dialog box of Vlookup function. I am trying the below code but all it does in open the Insert Function dialog box

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Vlookup(,,,)"
ActiveCell.FunctionWizard
```

if i try to run the macro on the same cell again it apparently opens the Vlookup Function Argument.Any ideas how can i get keyboard shortcut for Vlookup in one flow

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start.

Assign a shortcut key to the following:

```
Sub MakeVLOOKUP()
    Dim i1 As String, i2 As String, i3 As String, i4 As String

    i1 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter first argument", Type:=2) & ","
    i2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter second argument", Type:=2) & ","
    i3 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter third argument", Type:=2)

    ActiveCell.Formula = "=vlookup(" & i1 & i2 & i3 & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried a sample data by referencing a range, however it does not reflect the range i select in the variables